# My API call creates a record even after the return statement?

Tags: node.js, express

this will be a simple answer, but I have this code, that validates if a record exists in the database, and It does, and I got a status 500 from the API call, but keeps creating the duplicate record in my table.

```
exports.createBet = async (req, res)=>{
        betBody = req.body;
        newBalance = 0.0;
        Bet.findOne({
            where: {
                [Op.and]: [
                    {match_id: betBody.matchId},
                    {user_id: betBody.userId}
                ]
            }
        }).then(data=>{
            if(data){
                return res.status(500).send({message: "Bet already made for this match"});
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            return res.status(500).send({ message: "Error creation the bet: " + err.message});
        });
        balnce = await User.findOne({
            where:{
                id: betBody.userId
            }
        })
        .then(data=>{
            if(data.balance < betBody.betAmount){
                return res.status(500).send({ message: "Not enough balance to make that bet."});
            }
            return data.balance;
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            return res.status(500).send({ message : "Error getting the user in the bet creation: " + err.message})
        });
        Bet.create({
            match_id: betBody.matchId,
            bet_amount: betBody.betAmount,
            selected_winner: betBody.teamSelect,
            user_id: betBody.userId
        })
        .then(data=>{
            res.json(data)
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            return res.status(500).send({ message: "Error creating the bet: " + err.message})
        });
        newBalance = balnce - betBody.betAmount;
        User.update(
            { balance: newBalance},
            { where: {id: betBody.userId}}
        )
        .catch(err=>{
            res.status(500).send({ message: "Error getting user: " + err.message})
        });
    };
```

[Here it is the response of the api call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da84V.png)

[And here it is the duplicated records in my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95iYG.png)

Comment: Your code contains three separate promise chains that are all running in parallel.  A return in one doesn't affect the others, it just finishes that promise chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the promise chain(or async/await correctly) to solve this issue, When a request reaches to createBet function every database call(without await one) is executing parallel, it creates a new record while checking for the existing one.

**NOTE**: Sometimes You might get a response already sent error. res.send does not stop execution it'll return the response but the remaining code will still execute.

```
exports.createBet = async (req, res) => {
  betBody = req.body;
  newBalance = 0.0;
  try {
    const bet = await Bet.findOne({
      where: {
        [Op.and]: [{ match_id: betBody.matchId }, { user_id: betBody.userId }],
      },
    }).catch((err) => {
      throw { message: "Error creation the bet: " + err.message };
    });

    if (bet) {
      throw { message: "Bet already made for this match" };
    }
    //... handle the cases like above, must use await
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem causes in your database a saved record without all the fields trying to truncate your table and start a fresh,

I think here in your query all time finds a record(data) thats why we are facing this type of error

If it's not work try to debug your code with log your data which comes from your `findOne` query